# Unable to parse bind variables in Execute Immediate inside FORALL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a PL/SQL Procedure which uses **For loop** and inserts around 5000 records.

I'm trying to use **FORALL** as I get performance issue with **For loop**.

I'm passing Table name,sequence id, column name list (**I_columnnames** as comma separated string), columns datatype (as comma separated string), multiple record level data (as comma separated string)

**I_columnnames** will have multiple column names (The number of columns vary for each execution)
I have format the each record level data as per corresponding datatype in one collection **v_tab** (eg.**'REC01',1500,100,100,TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-10-10','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FF3')**)

Now, I have to insert record level data in this dynamic table and for this I am using FORALL statement with execute immediate as below :

```
FORALL i IN v_tab.first .. v_tab.last 
   
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' ||I_tablename||'  (BLCK_ID, SEQ_ID, '||I_columnnames|| ')
   values ('''|| I_blckid||''' ,'||I_sequence||' ,'||':1'||')' using v_tab(i);
```

But I am getting **ORA - not enough values** error as bind variable :1 has been considered as single string (although it has multiple comma separted values)

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` inside `FORALL` did not work due to bind variable with dynamic columns.

Using `INSERT ALL` instead of conventional `INSERT` worked fine and improved the performance.

Answer (score 1):

`:1` *is* a single string containing your comma separated values, it isn't expanded to all the individual elements.

As you discovered, concatenating the string instead:

```
...I_sequence||' ,'|| v_tab(i) ||')';
```

gets "PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL".

You could potentially still concatenate the string but in a normal `for` loop instead of with `forall`:

```
for i in v_tab.first .. v_tab.last loop
  execute immediate 'INSERT INTO ' ||i_tablename||' (BLCK_ID, SEQ_ID, '||i_columnnames|| ')'
      || ' values ('''|| i_blckid||''' ,'||i_sequence||' ,' || v_tab(i) || ')';
end loop;
```

assuming your CSV string has the appropriate quotes within it and does any necessary conversions, which seems to be the case - though your example is invalid - and it's risky from a SQL injection point of view.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=497bc9a57ef563f6fb87557c0c0d7d83)

You could look at `dbms_sql` instead of `execute immediate` but I don't think it will offer much of an improvement. You may be better off revisiting how and why you construct `v_tab`. You could also possibly use a dynamic PL/SQL block within your existing one, built by manipulating your strings; but with only 5000 rows any speed or efficiency gain over the simple loop probably won't be worth it. It could avoid the SQL injection issue though.

Comment: This is not working as it is inside FORALL. It throws the error --> Error: PLS-00435: DML statement without BULK In-BIND cannot be used inside FORALL

Comment: Right, well it isn't a good idea anyway, as I said. You'll need to rethink this. If you edit the question to explain where how the parameters (v_tab etc.) are populated then we may be able to suggest a better way of doing things. Or ask a new question giving all the necessary information.

Comment: I have added a sample of how v_tab is being populated as you suggested.

Comment: You can add (and accept) your own answer if you want to show how you solved your issue, if you think it will be useful for other people.